# AngularJs two way binding not working with Jquery plugin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I tried to use Angular with JQuery autocomplete plugin.
My problem with update parent scope after select option in autocomplete.
Two way binding working well for insert text by keyboard but not from JS.

I have found some similar question on StackOverflow but looks like it is not wotking for me.
I tried to use $scope.$apply or fire "input" events but it is not working.
You can find my Javascript and html here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

    <link href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('testApplication', []);

        app.directive('ngAutocomplete', function () {
            var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                transclude: true,
                link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    $(iElement).autocomplete(months).
                    on("result", function (event, result) {
                        console.log(result[0])
                        scope.$apply();
                        $(iElement).trigger('input');
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.EditModel = {};
            $scope.EditModel.Customer = "";
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="testApplication" ng-controller="testController">
        Month:
        <input ng-autocomplete ng-model="EditModel.Customer" />
        <input ng-model="EditModel.Customer" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can find plunker with my example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/u21NSJDlaW1bAkUjOMtB

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to require the `ngModel` controller in your directive an set the models view value manualy when the user selects an item. Here is an working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wBgmJ163X6kATKypuTrS?p=preview

The magic happens in your `result` callback:

```
scope.$apply(function () {
  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(result[0]);
});
```

To use the `ngModelCtrl` you have to require it in your directive via `require : 'ngModel'` and set the controller as a new parameter in the `link` method.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove the dependency for JQuery and replace the autocomplete functionality with your own directive or from the pool of AngularJs autocomplete directives? A good one I use is http://ngmodules.org/modules/angucomplete.